# Transfer the text of a variable from VB.NET form to Excel worksheet

Tags: vb.net, excel, visual-studio-2013

I want to save the contents of text boxes in a form to an Excel worksheet. I wrote the following VB.NET class to save all the data to variables using a button click:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim A1 As String
    Dim A2 As String
    Dim A3 As String
    Dim B1 As String
    Dim B2 As String
    Dim B3 As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        A1 = A1textbox.Text
        A2 = A2textbox.Text
        A3 = A3textbox.Text
        B1 = B1textbox.Text
        B2 = B2textbox.Text
        B3 = B3textbox.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 but I am not very familiar with Visual Basic. How do I transfer text from these variables into an Excel worksheet?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301982

Comment: You should do a little more research, read the support article linked in the above comment, and show us a more complete attempt. You might be able to solve the problem yourself, and if you encounter an error, we're much better at solving those than giving out general guidance